# WebSocket connection attempt not interrupted by Flux timeout in Micronaut

Tags: java, websocket, micronaut

I am encountering an issue while working with WebSocket connections in Micronaut 3.9.0. I am attempting to set a timeout for the WebSocket connection, and despite my efforts, the timeout doesn't seem to interrupt the connection attempt as expected.

I've tried using the timeout operator on the Flux object, but it doesn't seem to be working as I think. The connection attempt continues beyond the specified timeout.

Sample code:

```java
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.context.BeanContext;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketClient;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketSession;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.ClientWebSocket;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnClose;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnMessage;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnOpen;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.awaitility.Awaitility;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

@Slf4j
@MicronautTest
class WstimeoutTest {
    static AtomicBoolean isOpened = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Inject
    BeanContext beanContext;

    @ClientWebSocket
    static abstract class TestWebSocketClient implements AutoCloseable {
        @OnMessage
        void onMessage(String message) {
            log.info("[onMessage] Got message: {}", message);
        }

        @OnOpen
        void onOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
            log.info("[onOpen] WS session id: {}", session.getId());
            isOpened.set(true);
        }

        @OnClose
        void onClose(WebSocketSession session) {
            log.info("[onClose] WS session id: {}", session.getId());
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testWebSocketTimeout() {
        var uri = "ws://localhost";
        var timeout = Duration.ofMillis(40); //Put here the time that ws client is unable to establish (or emit OnOpen event) websocket connection

        var webSocketClient = beanContext.getBean(WebSocketClient.class);

        Publisher<TestWebSocketClient> client = webSocketClient.connect(TestWebSocketClient.class,  uri);
        Flux.from(client)
                .timeout(timeout)
                .doOnError(throwable -> log.info("Expected error: {}", throwable.getMessage()))
                .subscribe();


        Awaitility.await().atLeast(Duration.ofMillis(250)).untilAsserted(
                () -> Assertions.assertFalse(isOpened.get(), "WebSocket should not be opened")
        );
    }
}
```

The test output:

```
2023:11:21T13:24:56.140 [parallel-1] INFO  com.example.WstimeoutTest[][] - Expected error: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 40ms in 'switchMapNoPrefetch' (and no fallback has been configured)
2023:11:21T13:24:56.178 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] INFO com.example.WstimeoutTest[][] - [onOpen] WS session id: AOKppbvUUl5zc3/x1N0lBiXW4WU=

WebSocket should not be opened
Expected :false
Actual   :true
```

Is there any way to properly timeout the WebSocket connection?

Answer (score -1):

You are asserting the value that hasn't been altered in the `onClose()` method:

```
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.context.BeanContext;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketClient;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketSession;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.ClientWebSocket;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnClose;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnMessage;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnOpen;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.awaitility.Awaitility;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

@Slf4j
@MicronautTest
class WstimeoutTest {
    static AtomicBoolean isOpened = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Inject
    BeanContext beanContext;

    @ClientWebSocket
    static abstract class TestWebSocketClient implements AutoCloseable {
        @OnMessage
        void onMessage(String message) {
            log.info("[onMessage] Got message: {}", message);
        }

        @OnOpen
        void onOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
            log.info("[onOpen] WS session id: {}", session.getId());
            isOpened.set(true);
        }

        @OnClose
        void onClose(WebSocketSession session) {
            log.info("[onClose] WS session id: {}", session.getId());
            isOpened.set(false);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testWebSocketTimeout() {
        var uri = "ws://localhost";
        var timeout = Duration.ofMillis(40); //Put here the time that ws client is unable to establish (or emit OnOpen event) websocket connection

        var webSocketClient = beanContext.getBean(WebSocketClient.class);

        Publisher<TestWebSocketClient> client = webSocketClient.connect(TestWebSocketClient.class,  uri);
        Flux.from(client)
                .timeout(timeout)
                .doOnError(throwable -> log.info("Expected error: {}", throwable.getMessage()))
                .subscribe();


        Awaitility.await().atLeast(Duration.ofMillis(250)).untilAsserted(
                () -> Assertions.assertFalse(isOpened.get(), "WebSocket should not be opened")
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe I've found a solution after researching and experimenting with `HttpClientConfiguration`. The solution involves setting the `ConnectTimeout` for the HttpClient :)

Additionally, in the case of connections to localhost, time limits may be ignored because communication occurs within the same environment(?) (at least below code fails even if I set `httpTimeout = Duration.ofNanos(1)` for local server). To test this, I utilized an online echo WebSocket server. Below is the complete example code along with my results:

```java
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.context.BeanContext;
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientConfiguration;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import io.micronaut.websocket.CloseReason;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketClient;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketSession;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.ClientWebSocket;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnClose;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnError;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnMessage;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.OnOpen;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.awaitility.Awaitility;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

@Slf4j
@MicronautTest
class WstimeoutTest {
    static AtomicBoolean isOpened = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    static AtomicBoolean isCompleted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    static AtomicReference<CloseReason> closeReasonAtomicReference = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Inject
    BeanContext beanContext;


    @ClientWebSocket
    static abstract class TestWebSocketClient implements AutoCloseable {
        @OnMessage
        void onMessage(String message, WebSocketSession session) {
            log.info("[onMessage] Got message: {}", message);
            session.close(CloseReason.NORMAL);
        }

        @OnOpen
        void onOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
            log.info("[onOpen] WS session id: {}", session.getId());
            isOpened.set(true);
            session.close(CloseReason.NORMAL);
        }

        @OnError
        void onError(Throwable err, WebSocketSession session) {
            log.error("[onError] WS session id: {}, with error: {}", session.getId(), err.getMessage());
        }

        @OnClose
        void onClose(CloseReason closeReason, WebSocketSession session) {
            log.info("[onClose] WS session id: {}, close code: {}", session.getId(), closeReason.getCode());
            closeReasonAtomicReference.set(closeReason);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testWebSocketTimeout() {
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI("<provide address to external WS server>");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        var fluxTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(2000);
//        var httpTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(400); // within this time client is able to establish connection
        var httpTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(30); // within this time the ws client is unable to establish websocket connection and ends/throws close code 1006

        var httpClientConfiguration = beanContext.getBean(HttpClientConfiguration.class);

        httpClientConfiguration.setConnectTimeout(httpTimeout);

        var webSocketClient = beanContext.getBean(WebSocketClient.class);

        Publisher<TestWebSocketClient> client = webSocketClient.connect(TestWebSocketClient.class, uri);

        var disposable = Flux.from(client)
                .timeout(fluxTimeout)
                .doFinally(unused -> isCompleted.set(true))
                .subscribe(
                        testWebSocketClient -> {
                            isOpened.set(true);
                            log.info("Success");
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            isOpened.set(false);
                            log.info("Expected error: {}", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                        }
                );

        Awaitility.await().atMost(fluxTimeout).pollInterval(Duration.ofMillis(50))
                .untilAsserted(
                        () -> Assertions.assertTrue(isCompleted.get(), "WebSocket should be completed")
                );

        Awaitility.await().atMost(fluxTimeout).pollInterval(Duration.ofMillis(50))
                .untilAsserted(
                () -> Assertions.assertFalse(isOpened.get(), "WebSocket should not be opened")
        );
        Awaitility.await().atMost(fluxTimeout).pollInterval(Duration.ofMillis(50))
                .untilAsserted(
                () -> Assertions.assertNotEquals(CloseReason.NORMAL, closeReasonAtomicReference.get(),
                        "WebSocket should not be opened")
        );

        disposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
> Task :testClasses
2023:12:02T14:54:12.335 [Test worker] INFO  i.m.c.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment[][] - Established active environments: [test]
2023:12:02T14:54:13.286 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] INFO  com.example.WstimeoutTest[][] - Expected error: Error opening WebSocket client session: Abnormal Closure
io.micronaut.websocket.exceptions.WebSocketClientException: Error opening WebSocket client session: Abnormal Closure
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.websocket.NettyWebSocketClientHandler.handleCloseReason(NettyWebSocketClientHandler.java:262)
    (...)
> Task :test
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
```

It appears that there is no specific `TimeoutException`, but instead a `WebSocketClientException` with information about an `Abnormal Closure`. Additionally, no WS events are triggered, such as `onOpen`, `onMessage`, `onClose`, or `onError` as expected.